# Dynamically generate command-line command, then invoke using powershell

Tags: powershell

Using powershell, you can use the '&' character to run another application and pass in parameters.

A simple example.

```
$notepad = 'notepad'
$fileName = 'HelloWorld.txt'

# This will open HelloWorld.txt
& $notepad $fileName
```

This is good. But what if I want to use business logic to dynamically generate a command string? Using the same simple example:

```
$commandString = @('notepad', 'HelloWorld.txt') -join ' ';
& $commandString
```

I get the error:

> The term 'notepad HelloWorld.txt' is
>   not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet, function, script file, or
>   operable program. Check the spelling
>   of the name, or if a path was
>   included, verify that the path is
>   correct and try again.

In my real example I'm trying to dynamically add or remove options to the final command line string. Is there a way I can go about this?

Comment: Does quoting in double quotes ("") help?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Two ways to do that:

1. **Separate the exe from the arguments**

   Do all your dynamic stuff for the arguments, but call the exe as normal with the variable holding the arguments afterward:

   ```
   $exe = 'notepad'
   $argument = '"D:\spaced path\HelloWorld.txt"'
   &$exe $argument

   #or
   notepad $argument
   ```

   If you have more than one argument, you should make it an array if it will be separate from the exe part of the call:

   ```
   $exe = 'notepad'
   $arguments = '"D:\spaced path\HelloWorld.txt"','--switch1','--switch2'
   &$exe $arguments
   ```
2. **Use Invoke-Expression**

   If everything must be in a string, you can invoke the string as if it were a normal expression. `Invoke-Expression` also has the alias of `iex`.

   ```
   $exp = 'notepad "D:\spaced path\HelloWorld.txt"'
   Invoke-Expression $exp
   ```

In either case, the contents of the arguments and of the exe should be quoted and formatted appropriately as if it were being written straight on the commandline.

Comment: Note also that you need to quote arguments within the single string yourself to ensure they are passed properly.

Comment: Thanks. This question gave me three usable alternatives, but I finally went with the "Separate the exe from the arguments" path.

Comment: @Andrew: I use that approach most of the time, too, since most languages have a similar separation for starting other processes.

Comment: Thanks for Invoke-Expression. Didnt know the power of it

Comment: Invoke-Expression does not work if I have spaces in the executable, like '"c:\my programs\notepad.exe" "D:\spaced path\HelloWorld.txt"' I get the error "Unexpected token in expression of statement"

Answer (score 8):

If you want to keep that logic for building your strings:

```
$commandString = @('notepad', 'HelloWorld.txt') -join ' '

&([scriptblock]::create($commandstring))
```

Comment: This does does preserve spaces in arguments, so won't work for 'Hello World.txt'